# How can I customize the permission dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Suppose I request a permission at runtime like the following:

```java
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    thisActivity,
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS}
);
```

The Android system creates a popup dialog to request permission. How can I define a custom layout for that dialog?

Comment: You can't, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097218/android-m-custom-permission-dialog-style

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The short answer is: **you can't**.

As the Android documentation puts it:

> When your app calls requestPermissions(), the system shows a standard dialog box to the user. Your app **cannot** configure or alter that dialog box. If you need to provide any information or explanation to the user, you should do that before you call requestPermissions(), as described in "Explain why the app needs permissions".

In summary: There is no way to define a custom layout for the permission dialog for now.

You can find more detailed information here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: "android... allows you to add some text to that dialog explaining the user why you are requesting that permission" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: @CommonsWare i thought the developer could explain the rationale of using that permission is that wrong? or just android shows its default explanation about that permission?

Comment: You can find out, via `shouldShowPermissionRequestRationale()`, whether you might want to show an explanation. However, you have to do that in your own UI. You cannot add prose to the system dialog for that.

Comment: Hi , **it's 2024**, I am creating android app and upload to 'huawei' , they actually required you do it like ios's `Info.plist`. So is should can , at least to 'huawei' it should be able to do it...

Answer (score 22):

I have create custom dialog for permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
       AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
       alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
       alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
       alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);}});

       AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
       alert.show();
   } else { 
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);}
    return false;} 
 else { 
     return true;
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Looks like this just create a new dialogue that when clicked yes, will trigger the system permission dialogue, it does not change the actual permission dialog in Android.

No different than calling ActivityCompat.requestPermissions... directly

Comment: @BabyishTank : You can not customize system dialog. It's just to create a customize dialog with your own custom message. You can directly call with system permission dialogue.

Comment: What if I have a custom permission, not a system standard one?

Answer (score 0):

[Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Cannot write to SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card) this post helped me out from showing dialog to grant write to external permission