# Is it possible to display a custom message when android application is requesting permission to use the gps, bluetooth, etc... before installation

Tags: android, permissions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO31v.png

There is an android application what request permission to use bluetooth and gps before install. Is it possible to diplay message with custom content at this moment?

Comment: Nope. That would make it possible to hide the permissions and would be a security risk

Answer (score 0):

you cannot , 
please see this link , already questioned before:

[How can i customize permission dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266328/how-can-i-customize-permission-dialog-in-android)