# On installation explaining why permission is needed

Tags: android, permissions

I need android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE declared in manifest of an app I'm developing. Is there a way to explain to a user why I need this permission at install (optimal) or at run time? So when app is installed something like "This permission is needed to use custom levels" is displayed? I need external, not application directory write permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the default permissions dialog box ([Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266328/how-can-i-customize-permission-dialog-in-android)).

However, you can have a dialog box pop up just before user gives permission for the first time. In the dialog box you can have the content you want with two button **continue** and **cancel**. When user selects continue then you can let default permission dialog box pop-up.

But as said by DaveNOTDavid this is not the best practice. As a hobbyist it is alright otherwise mention it in the Terms and Condition or Privacy Policy, as mentioned above.

**Edit**: I was reading the Documentation and found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)). It might be helpful for version 23.0.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, your only option is to use a **privacy policy page** that explicitly states what each dangerous permission in the app is used for.