# Android Java - Is it possible to keep navigation bar hidden when requesting for permission

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

Is it possible to keep the navigation bar hidden when requesting for a permission in android? I currently have it hidden on all my activities by using the following code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

When i then request for permission the navigation bar pops up... I can not seem to find an answer anywhere, and i'm unsure if it is even possible.

Comment: permission requesting prompts are not our application based. So, i think we have no control on it. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266342/7910735

Comment: no you can not until you create customised pop ups and use them to request the permissions manually but why go the difficult way?

Comment: @SahdeepSing thanks for the link :)

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal the reason is that i hate when its not perfect, even though it is only first time you launch the app, that it will ever happen

Comment: @Emil refer to the last answer of this and try it out and then let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266328/how-can-i-customize-permission-dialog-in-android/33266342#33266342#37296542

Comment: I wonder why you say it's not perfect? What do you mean exactly? What do you mean by navigation bar by the way? Do you mean the `ActionBar`? This sounds like something coming from iOS?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I decided not to check it out, and just let it be as it is, it seemed like alot of trouble for such a little thing.

Comment: @Darwind I am referring to the bar which appear on the bottom of phones which does not physically have a "home", "back" , "and the last button" button on their phone but instead on the display

Comment: @Emil ah yes - I believe it's usually referred to as the `system navigation bar` as it's a system bar. But nonetheless: why do you want to remove it? Unless you're making a game there should be absolutely no reason to remove this bar. If you remove it you force the user to make a decision to either accept or decline your permission request - what if I as a user don't want to make this decision right away?