# Change allow camera usage permission message in android

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-manifest, android-permissions

How to change "Allow 'appname' to take pictures and record video?" android native permission message to "Allow 'appname' to take pictures for 'functionality name' " custom message?

Is that even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize permission dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266328/how-can-i-customize-permission-dialog-in-android)

Comment: Also see [this part of the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#explain)

Answer (score 0):

Using requestPermissions() is not allowing to change the native permission message.