# Android AlertDialog like the Permissions Dialog in Android 10 and above

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I have been searching for example when I can customize my AlertDialog in the same way the permissions are asked on Android 10 and above, with all the options in between and center aligned.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize permission dialog in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266328/how-can-i-customize-permission-dialog-in-android)

Comment: No, actually, I don't want to customize the permissions dialog. I want my alertdialogs in the application to be shown in a similar style as it would help in the overall UI being consistent.

Comment: Create a Layout and set it to your `AlertDialog`([how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)), the layout is pretty basic as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed such a dialog in one of my projects named OptionalDialog. With this custom dialog, you can add one, two, or three options to the dialog. You can add a hint to your dialog too. To find out more, please visit the class on my [GitHub account](https://github.com/yahyalmh/Apod/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/yaya/apod/ui/component/OptionalDialog.kt).

[image: OptionalDialog with three options]